# Why does the symbol for implication vary from class to class, university to university?

Tags: soft-question, notation

#### Some (neccesary) background and motivation for my question:

In some of my undergraduate math classes, specifically my proofs course, I have been required to use the $\Rightarrow$ symbol to denote any implication. In fact, my professor told me that we reserve $\rightarrow$ for "different things in math, like limits". This was at the university that I currently study at and many of my math professors use this notation. This is what I am used to to denote an implication of any sort. This class is specific to the mathematics major.

This summer, I decided to take a discrete math class online with the University of North Dakota. In submitting an assignment very similar in scope and content, even *identical* to the assignments at my home university, the professor told us that we are to use $\rightarrow$ as $\Rightarrow$ is reserved for much more formal mathematics.

**This assignment was identical in content and scope as an assignment I had in my proofs class**

Another student at my university back at home noted that $\Rightarrow$ denotes a biconditional in discrete math, but I had been taught since *high school* and all the way up through university mathematics (I am a junior math major now) that the biconditional is denoted with $\iff$.

Even if $\Rightarrow$ did denote a biconditional in discrete math, then why does $\leftrightarrow$ exist?

#### My question:

> Why do these differences exist, what *are* these differences, and why do they seem to be particular to discrete mathematics?

I would appreciate any and all insight.

Comment: "Another student at my university back at home noted that $\implies$ denotes a biconditional in discrete math" -- I highly, highly doubt this. (**Edit:** Not that the student told you, but that it is true.) I would be shocked if anyone could show me a textbook with this (terrible) convention.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Hmm. So I can say that it does *not* denote, the biconditional. By the way, I saw your edit!

Comment: in my experience, $\rightarrow$ is used by students who have not yet taken a class on formal logic/proof writing, and doesn't have a precise mathematical meaning.

Comment: Aha! So I *am* being duped by this prof at another uni! it appears that way. I have taken that more formal proofs class already.  @Glougloubarbaki

Comment: See [Material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) for references and discussion: the symbol has a long history and it symbolize a difficult concept with a never-ending philosophical discussion; this (in part) explains the difficulty to agree on a "standard".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In reading, it states that $\Rightarrow$ is a logical consequence. It then states that it means something follows from something. But how does $\rightarrow$ not do this? Is $\rightarrow$ *less rigorous* then? Unfortunately, this is seemingly a hand-wavey argument from someone on wikipedia. I am hoping there is a clear difference between a "logical implication which has a consequence that follows from something" and "material conditional".

Comment: You can find tens of similar questions (with good answers) on this site. The issue is that we have several concepts in place : the *conditional* (the propositional conncetive) : $\to$ or $\supset$; the derivability relation in a formal system : $\vdash$; the *logical consequence* relation : $\vDash$. An then we have the $\Rightarrow$ symbol: someone uses it in place of $\to$, someone uses it in place of $\vDash$. Conclusion: up to now there is **no** International Mathematical Symbolism Standardization Office...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do these differences exist, what *are* these differences, and why do they seem to be particular to discrete mathematics?

Of course I can't speak to your specific context, but I very strongly suspect that it is simply that notation is used slightly differently in different places, each with their own convention. To students convention is often presented as fact (and sometimes this is not even bad -- e.g., the convention that multiplication binds more strongly than addition is so strong that it might as well be a fact).

The only time I have seen a strong distinction between $\implies$ and $\to$ is in logic, where $\to$ is the *syntactical implication*, used in formal sentences like $\forall x(P(x) \to Q(x))$, while $\implies$ is used for meta-language implication, the language in which you state theorems and proofs. E.g:

> **Theorem:** For $\Gamma$ a set of formulas, and $\phi, \psi$ formulas, we have that
>   $$
> \Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi \implies \Gamma,\phi \vdash \psi.
> $$

Outside of this I have only ever seen $\to$ and $\implies$ used more or less interchangeably (although typically consistently within a single text).

Comment: At my university, the PhD's are very set on *not* using them interchangeably. If I wrote $\rightarrow$ on an exam at my school, it would be points off, or a note to not use such notation in favor of $\Rightarrow$. However, at UND, the professor perhaps simply does not want student using $\Rightarrow$ without understanding *how* to properly use it. Since discrete math is open to computer science students and others, is that perhaps why you think they might only use $\rightarrow$ instead of $\Rightarrow$ ? Is it that students in discrete math are too mathematically immature?

Comment: No, I do not think that is the reason. What would it mean that they are not mature enough to use $\implies$ "properly" if they are instead using $\to$ to express the same thing? Notation has no intrinsic meaning. The only reason I'd see teachers taking points off for using the wrong arrow is that, once a convention is established, the ability to follow the convention demonstrates that you understand the convention and thus the material. (Consider a student who confuses $x = -1 \implies x^2 = 1$ with $(1/n) \to 0$.) That, *or* the teachers are just passing on a convention they were taught.

Comment: In an above comment, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA seems to differentiate between the two notations as there being an actual difference. Apparently $\rightarrow$ is more for the logician and $\Rightarrow$ is more mathematically motivated and reserved moreso for theorems and lemmas.

Comment: *Apparently* $\rightarrow$ *is more for the logician and* $\Rightarrow$ *is more mathematically motivated* --- Keep in mind that for many decades there were typographical issues, and something like $\Rightarrow$ was much more difficult for publishers to work with than $\rightarrow.$ In fact, I don't even believe $\Rightarrow$ was used until maybe the 1960s or later. Since math papers rarely needed the $\Rightarrow$ symbol (it's used a lot now probably because it's a LaTeX character), one just says "implies", **(continued)**

Comment: @SincerelyPrime, I would argue that this differentiation is similar to the one I make in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I really appreciate the insight. It makes better sense now, thank you!

Comment: while books and papers in logic made heavy use of a symbol for implication, I suspect the current distinction between what mathematicians use and what logicians use originates from inertia based on earlier typographical issues.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and because I happen to know where my course notes are right now, I checked the earliest course notes I have in which the symbol $\Rightarrow$ might appear --- Fall 1976 handwritten notes I took in the first semester of a 2-semester sequence I took during the 1976-77 academic year using Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" text. In several places in those notes the symbol $\Rightarrow$ appears.